# Xamarin Image Forms Base64 not showing

Tags: android, image, xamarin.forms, stream, base64

I'm pretty new to Xamarin , i want to change image source after clicking a button , using FromStream method and base64 string , but after run application no image showing , here is my code :
note : i test my Base64 String on online convertor and it's ok ... (https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" Source="" HeightRequest="50"  WidthRequest="50" />

string imgBase64 = "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";

var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64);
var stream1 = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
```

Comment: have you verified that `byteArray` contains valid image data after decoding?

Comment: I ran your code without any issues. Try to run the code on an empty page with just a single `Image` control.

Comment: thank you , but how i can verify byteArray  ?
i verify base64 string on this website : https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: i have no error when run the code , but no image show on page ...

Comment: You can create a new xamarin app ,and copy your code in this new app . You code  works on my test app.